# Excluding fields with same name from indexing

Tags: indexing, azure-search

I want to exclude two fields with the same name from indexing.
Can I have two entries in the DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file in the exclude list or is there any other way ?

Example below where `Parameters_template` is the field name.

```
<Parameters_template>{04F2D6D8-7748-425C-A435-B63C4FFBF43E}</Parameters_template>
<Parameters_template>{9003574A-FB95-4FC3-B17C-33893DAD35A9}</Parameters_template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name you use in the configuration is actually meaningless (unless for readability) so yes, you can. I'm not sure however that it will work if you have the same entry multiple times - suggestion: just try it ;)

But, as mentioned, you can easily get what you need with this:

```
<ParametersTemplate1>{...}</ParametersTemplate1>
<ParametersTemplate2>{...}</ParametersTemplate2>
```